# Error on jquery post.error()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the ongoing saga of me both learning new to me tech and becoming familiar with my predecessor's code, I have the following snippet which when run (minified - another mystery is how this is happening on the back end, but I'll save that for later) I get the following error:

[image: minified version of code above]

Why isn't `post(...).on` a function? Or, what is going wrong that I need to change/fix?

```js
$('form button[type=submit]').on('click', () => {
  const donation = getDonation();

  $.post(
    '//localhost:61686/api/Donation',
    donation,
    (data) => {
      console.log(`post succeeded:[${JSON.stringify(data)}]`);
    }
  ).on('error', ((xhr, errorType, ex) => {
      console.log(`post error:[${JSON.stringify(xhr)}]`);
      console.log(`post error:[${errorType}]`);
      console.log(`post error:[${JSON.stringify(ex)}]`);
    }).fail((data) => {
      console.log(`post failed:[${JSON.stringify(data)}]`);
    })
    .always((data) => {
      console.log(`post complete:[${JSON.stringify(data)}]`);
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would there be on(error) and .fail?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ `var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });`

Comment: @Daerik - I can't use slim because I'm trying to do a .post(). I had earlier thought that was the problem, but alas not.

Comment: @mplungjan - this is me learning all the way around. :-) Your question prompted me to look up the difference between the two. And is prompting me to look up the meanings of those other things. Thank you!  Also, thank you for the link. Basically, I was given badly written code. :-)

Comment: @NovaDev I deleted the comment because I had misread your question. `.on()` is an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. You are attempting to bind using a HTTP POST request, which I think goes against the documentation. There are ways to catch errors from a jqXHR Object, I would strongly suggest reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this: Read the docs regarding jQuery.post. You'll see that .fail and .on('error,...) are redundant, and in fact, that `.error()` is deprecated and removed from `jquery >= 3.0`, and that the only available and useful methods are `.done()`, `.fail()`, and `.always()`.

That means that I inherited badly written code, and I didn't know it, but that thanks to some great commenters, I got the answers that I needed.